# How to send an email to someone upon approval of a new list item

Tags: email, approval

I have a non-OOB approval workflow I created through SharePoint Designer 2013 (using a 2010 platform). That approval process works great, but I want to send an email to HR (to one individual) upon the approval of this item with the details of this item populated in the email.

My thoughts are this (my approval workflow is creatively called "Approval Workflow"):

(Step 1 is the working approval)

Step: Step 2

```
If Current Item:Approval Workflow equals Current Item:Approval Workflow:0#;Approved
    Email Current Item:HR Representative
    Set content approval status to Approved with Email Sent to HR
    Stop the workflow and log Completed Approval and HR Notified
Else
    Wait for Approval Workflow to equal Current Item:Approval Workflow:0#;Approved
    Email Current Item:HR Representative
    Set content approval status to Approved with Email Sent to HR
    Stop the workflow and log Completed Approval and HR Notified
```

These are my thoughts, but I can't seem to make it work, I cannot select the 0#;Approved from any sort of drop-down menu in SharePoint Designer and when I put it in manually as I wrote above, it doesn't work.

Any advice on how to make this work would be awesome. The goal again is to simply send an email to HR once we approve an item in our list (department).

EDIT: (I edited the names to fit what I described above, that is why some don't have underlines)

This still does not work. Help?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need IF and ELSE in your second step. You rather use "wait" for Approval workflow to equal Current Item - workflow status column: Approved. 
Add "email notification" statement to send email to HR and Log it

If the above explanation doesn't help, please provide a screenshot of your workflow so I can explain it further

Comment: I did what you said, but it still is not working. I don't really know how to add a screenshot, but I added an edit into the original post

Comment: Is your workflow attached to your list/library? Please open your list/library in designer and make sure it is attached?

Comment: It definitely is. The only thing I can think of is that in this:

Wait for "Workflow Approval" "to equal" "Approved" 

I enter in "Approved" manually. I know it is coded as 0#;Approved and either way I enter them, no email is sent (currently testing my sending to myself). So I'm not sure SharePoint correctly recognizes that and I'm not sure how to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using approval action for approval in SharePoint 2013?

If you are using SharePoint 2013 then use create task action and in this action you can create your email body and enter users for you want to create task.

Then this task is wait for approve or reject so on the basis of approved or rejected you can send mail.

I think if you are using SharePoint 2013 then it is very easily handle using designer workflow in SharePoint 2013.

Comment: The idea is that we are routing approvals via email, so that management never goes into SharePoint unless they notice an issue. the goal is to replace paper processes via automation through SharePoint. I'm also new to SharePoint and have been working off and on to develop a pilot to test. Can you elaborate on how to use Tasks to accomplish this in 2013?

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps for create simple approval workflow in SharePoint 2013.

1)Create SharePoint 2013 workflow
2)Add create task action from actions
3)Create body and enter user for the users from you want to take approval
4)Now, just below this action check outcome from above action whether 0 or 1
5)If it is 0 then approved and 1 then rejected and based on that add new action send email

Please follow this link for task related information.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj614606.aspx